# script for finding all UI elements in code

Tags: ios, bash

I have a script line `find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj -o base.lproj`
to find all localized strings in the code text.

Is it possible to write a script to find all `:UI` elements
and write them to a file?

Comment: You could use `grep`.

Comment: can you tell me how ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'UI elements'? what exactly do you want to search for?

Comment: UIButtons, UILabels, UIViews

Comment: i want to write a script that will write all the instances of uiview type elements from my code into 1 file